# Is it necessary to add generics for implementation constructor when variable type is interface?

Tags: typescript, generics

Consider the following code:

```
//LINE 1
private result: Map<EventType<any>, number> = new HashMap<EventType<any>, number>();

//LINE 2
private result: Map<EventType<any>, number> = new HashMap();
```

Is it necessary to add generics for implementation constructor when variable type is interface? Is there any difference in TypeScript between these two lines of code?

Comment: I think you mean just `Map` not `HashMap`, or is the question more about the assignability of a subclass and it's relation to generics ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I wrote exactly that code, that I mean. I implement Java SE/JavaFX in TypeScript, you can see [Script4J](https://github.com/PavelKastornyy/script4j)

Comment: Ok, I was thinking of es2015 Map, that is what threw me off

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two line as far as runtime behavior is concerned. Types are fully erased at compile time so it should have no runtime impact.

Will the types type parameters workout to the same thing? Typescript will also do inference based on expected return value, so if it expects the result of the constructor to be `Map<EventType<any>, number>` it will work back that the type parameters to the `HashMap` constructor need to be `EventType<any>`  and `number`.

We can see this if we hover over the `HashMap` constructor:

```
export class Map<K, V> {
  get(k:K ): V { return null!; }
}

export class HashMap<K, V> extends Map<K, V> {
  get(k:K ): V { return null!; }
}


let o: Map<string, number> = new HashMap() // hover over HashMap and you will see constructor HashMap<string, number>(): HashMap<string, number>
```